# Disable HTML element tooltips in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, web-essentials

I was wondering if anyone has had any luck disabling the HTML element tooltips in Visual Studio 2015. I find them to be a real annoyance, especially when dragging/ctrl+dragging text around (they get in the way most the time). Here's a screenshot the feature in action (updated):

[image]

I Googled and was only able to find  [the post where the feature was announced](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/10/16/announcing-new-web-features-in-visual-studio-2013-update-4-rc.aspx), but no mentions of how to disable it. I checked my Visual Studio preferences and have "Auto list members" and "Parameter information" disabled for the HTML text editor.

Any ideas or suggestions?

**Update (10/16/2015):** I think this issue may be related to the Web Essentials package. I disabled the package and was able to make the tooltip show up, however, I don't currently have a computer with a default Visual Studio 2015 install to test my theory on. I updated the screenshot to reflect the actual tooltip I'm getting (the original one was the screenshot included in the linked blog post).

Comment: This annoys me as well... and I can confirm it is not Web Essentials.. any luck disabling this 'helpful' feature?

Comment: I had a very similar (useless and annoying) popup for HTML elements. The one I was seeing was caused by the Resharper extension. To disable, `Resharper > Options... > Environment > IntelliSense > Parameter Info` and uncheck "Automatically show parameter info in {x} milliseconds".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Go to: `Tools > Options... > Text Editor > HTML > General`

In the '**Statement completion**' section you will see an '**Auto list members**' checkbox, uncheck it.

[image]

---

However, I'm not sure if the feature above reffers to an in-design html editing or will only affect in specific html development environment (editing an html file for example), so I'll give an additional solution:

Go to: `Tools > Options... > Environment > Keayboard`

Here, find the command `Edit.ToggleCompletionMode` and assign the keyboard shortcut that you desire.

[image]

Then just use it when you wish to toggle the auto completion of members (including html members I supose).

### Update

Sorry If I confussed what you want, because with the absence of auto completion it will remove existance of tooltips but I don't know if you need auto completion suggestions or not.

Anyways, for tooltips you could try doing the same procedure I explained in the images above but with the "**Parameter Information**" checkbox and/or the corresponding keyboard shortcut, `Edit.ParameterInfo`. Because seems that html element tooltips are treated as parameter info.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's trying to disable the tooltips, not Intelisense.

Comment: @heavyd thanks to point that. I updated my answer. I hope it could be helpful for the OP.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I had already de-selected both options. I was hoping for an addon or command to disable, but ToggleCompletionMode seems a bit hardcore.

Comment: I thought about that at first, but since it has to do with a tool and not a programming topic per-se, I thought this was the place to ask the question. I'll flag it then.

Answer (score 1):

This was annoying the Hell out of me as well & I found that ElektroStudios' solution wasn't suitable in my case. I'm fairly sure that they are VS-native (definitely not Web-Essentials or ReSharper).

For VS2015 at least, the offending tool-tips are located within the file:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Schemas\1033\HTML\html.loc

Deleting the contents of this file has "disabled" the tool-tips for me, although I can't say whether this will be a permanent fix.

Comment: Several dozen updates later, the contents of this file doesn't seem to have been re-populated & I've not seen a return of the dreaded tooltips.

Comment: For VS2017 The location has changed to: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Editors\Schemas\HTML\1033\html.loc` (of course if you are using Community or Professional Edition change that path accordingly).

Comment: For VS2019 The location has changed to: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Languages\Schemas\HTML\1033\html.loc` (of course if you are using Community or Professional Edition change that path accordingly).